# Can I somehow change the mail sender?

Tags: php

I created a mail sender in php
it works perfectly 
my only problem is that in inbox the mail sender is something like this

```
uid99541@web.websupport.sk
```

is there a way to change that address?

Comment: Are you using the `mail()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You may specify additional headers through the `additional_headers` parameter of the `mail()` function (the 4th argument), like the "sender".

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
// sender
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";

mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
?>
```

---

Additionally, if you want some more appropriate names to be displayed in the inbox, you may put the email address in the angle brackets and put the name before that:

```
$headers = "From: Shiva Ayyadurai <webmaster@example.com>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what do you mean by that address. Must be a programmed one.

To use the mail function, simply use this:

```
<?php
$to = "johndoe@xyz.com";
$subject = "Your subject";
$msg = "Your Message.";
$headers = "From: admin@xyz.com";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
?>
```

All the best.